# Onclick add class to 2nd child div || Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add the "on" class to the second child, but my code doesn't seem to work. Is it possible? Or how is it possible?

I'm a rookie and have tried multiple several forums and tutorials before asking this question.

HTML

```
<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem1" onclick="addClass()">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem2" onclick="addClass()">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem3" onclick="addClass()">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
element{
display:none;
}

on{
display:initial;
}
```

Javascript

```
function addClass(){
  var element= document.getElementsByClassName("element").children;


  element[1].classList.add('on');
  element[1].value ="on";
}
```

CODEPEN:

http://codepen.io/salman15/pen/woaQQW?editors=1010

Comment: it should work i think

Comment: There is no `children` property of a NodeList.

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm not sure i understand your answer.

Comment: `screen.value` makes no sense being that`.value` property belongs to form elements and `screen` is a div. The only exception  to use `.value` is key pairs I guess do you have object literals or array of objects, sorry I don't see them...?

Comment: Wow the codepen is way different than the Snippet. Ok so you just want to add `.on` to second child?

Comment: @zer00ne Yes i want to add .on , no i haven't. Could you explain how to do it?

Comment: @Notorious_Creed Read my babbling disguised as an answer. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Snippet features two functions:

> `turnOn()` **function breakdown:**

- It is an event handler registered to the click event on the root element `<html>`, yes that's everything DOM. (`document.documentElement`).
- Get references to the `event.target` and collect all second children (`document.querySelectorAll('div div + div');`)
- Selector breakdown: Get the divs that are a descendant of a div (`div div`) ***and*** has a sibling the is positioned before it (or above it, if looking at the markup). I call them older brothers (`div + div`).
- Now iterate through the collection of second divs and on every iteration, compare `.e.target` with a second div to see if they are the same. (`if (tgt === sec) {`)
- When a match is found, add the on class.

> `turnOnAll()` **function:**

This does the same thing as it's cousin `turnOn()` the difference being that it's `event.target` is a button (<kbd>ALL</kbd> located at the top) and it will change second divs ***all at once***.

There are some interesting CSS properties in use, details are commented in the CSS.
**Note:** Instead of the parent being clicked, the `event.target` is the second div, if you prefer the `event.target` to be the parent still, let me know. Even though it's not very apparent in this case, making event listeners that way allows you to delegate events with plain JavaScript (jQuery `.on()` except I'm not sure if it can handle dynamically created elements like`.on()`). By delegating an event, you can register an event on a parent element and be able to determine which of it's children were clicked. That's just using ***one*** `eventListener`.

#### Snippet

```js
function turnOnAll() {
  var second = document.querySelectorAll('div div + div');
  var qty = second.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    second[i].classList.add('on');
  }
}


document.documentElement.addEventListener('click', turnOn, false);

function turnOn(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  var second = document.querySelectorAll('div div + div');
  var qty = second.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < qty; i++) {
    var sec = second[i];
    if (tgt === sec) {
      sec.classList.add('on');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div:before {
  content: attr(class);
  color: gold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
div.element {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 180px;
  color: white;
}
div.element:after {
  content: 'Parent-Pure CSS: Each div has a :before, content: attr(class) property which will display the class if any.';
}
div div:first-of-type:after {
  content: 'First Child-Pure CSS: :after, content, and desendant and first-of-type';
  border: 2px dashed cyan;
  color: cyan;
}
div div + div:after {
  content: 'Second Child-Pure CSS: :after, content, and desendant and sibling selector';
  border: 2px dashed red;
  color: red;
}
.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 80%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='turnOnAll()'>ALL</button>
<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem1">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem2">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--PARENT-->
<div class="element" id="elem3">

  <!--FIRST CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

  <!--SECOND CHILD-->
  <div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, fetch all the elements add "on" class to the second child of each element

```
var element= document.querySelectorAll(".element");
for(var i=0; i < element.length; i++){

    element[i].children[1].classList.add('on');
    element[i].children[1].value ="on";   

}
```